# Running Jax-rs 2.1 HTTP PATCH on Wildfly - 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, http-patch

I am trying to run a rest api with a **http patch** method on a **wildfly 10.1.0.Final**. If I made a request on this endpoint i get a **405 Method Not Allowed**.

I use *javax.javaee-api:8.0*.

**Patch**:

```
@PATCH
@Path("/documents/{id}")
public Response patchDocument(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @Valid PatchRequestSTO jsonPatch) {
    return ok(jsonPatch.toString()).build();
}
```

Response: 405 Method Not Allowed

```
Allow:OPTIONS, PUT
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 05 Jan 2018 07:55:44 GMT
Server:WildFly/10
X-Powered-By:Undertow/1
```

**Put:**

```
@PUT
@Path("/documents/{id}")
public Response putDocument(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @Valid PatchRequestSTO jsonPatch) {
    return ok(jsonPatch.toString()).build();
}
```

Response: 200 Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `javax.javaee-api:8.0` as dependency in your project? That is not enough to run a Java EE 8 application on WildFly 10.1.0.Final, because wildfly does not support it.

So you need an application server ([Glassfish](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/downloads/ri/README), [Open Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2017/11/24/java-ee-8-implementation-november-liberty-beta/), ...) that is supporting JavaEE 8 to use the new features.

Comment: thanks, you are right -> http://wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/WildFly-12-Plans-EE8-and-Move-to-Quarterly-Iterative-Releases-td5718321.html